# How to make function with Generic input type and multiple/optional input parameters

Tags: rust

Let's say I've the below function as baseline:

```rust
fn sum(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
```

and I want to replace it by a function that:

1. Accept different type of numerical input parameters (i32, f64, ..)
2. Accept different number of input parameters, 2, 3, 4, ... as the user enter
3. Can do the 4 basic mathematical operations
4. Returns the result with 3 decimals only

i.e. how to write a single function to run the following 2 statement:

```rust
let x = sum(2, 3.1);
let y = sum(4.2, 6.3, 5.2, 10);
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you focused on a single mathematical operation and explained how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best way is to do [`macro`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.24.0/book/first-edition/macros.html), and [below](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0cb7aac8d4a34e34f5d2153ce779ae61) is my approach, other answers are welcomed:

```rust
macro_rules! sum{
    ($($element:expr); *) => [
        {
            let mut sum = 0f64;
            $(sum += $element as f64;)*
            sum
        }
    ];
}
macro_rules! sub{
    ($first:expr, $($others:expr); *) => [
        {
            let mut sub = $first as f64;
            $(sub -= $others as f64;)*
            sub
        }
    ];
}

macro_rules! mul{
    ($($element:expr), *) => [{
            let mut mul = 1f64;
            $(mul *= $element as f64;)*
            format!("{:.3}", mul).parse::<f64>().unwrap()
    }];
}

macro_rules! div{
    ($first:expr, $second:expr) => [
        $first as f64 / $second as f64
    ];
}

macro_rules! math{
    ($op: expr, $first:expr, $($others:expr), *) => {
        match $op {
            "+" => {
                        let mut sum = $first as f64;
                        $(sum += $others as f64;)*
                        Ok(sum)
                    },
            "-" => {
                        let mut sub = $first as f64;
                        $(sub -= $others as f64;)*
                        Ok(sub)
                    },
            "*" => {
                        let mut mul = $first as f64;
                        $(mul *= $others as f64;)*
                        Ok(mul)
                    }
            "/" => {
                        let mut div = $first as f64;
                        $(div /= $others as f64;)*
                        Ok(div)
                    },                    
            _ => Err("no correct operation selected"),
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", math!("+", 1, 2).unwrap());
    match math!("+", 1, 2) {
        Err(e)  => println!("Error found: {error}", error  = e),
        Ok(r)   => println!("Result found: {result}", result = r), 
    };
    println!("{:.3}\n{:.3}\n{}\n{:.3}", sum!(1, 2.1, 3), sub!(1, 2.7, -3), mul!(2.12588, 3.5), div!(2.5, 3) );
}
```